# how to find next element in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

i have this [SQL](http://pastebin.com/B8ERBD4L)

it produces output like below

```
A 
B 
C 
D 
...... 
...... 
ZZZZ
```

lets say the user has given me "AZ". i want to return him "BA".
how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: On which logic you want to return BA against AZ. Please specify your logic properly or provide some sample input and output data.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: i want to return B against A. I want to return AA against Z. i want to return C against B

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Comment: Why use SQL to solve this problem? Why use a huge with-query rather than just creating a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SQL Server 2014 you are on the lucky side. There is `LEAD`

Add this to your last select

```
SELECT *
       ,LEAD(ALPHA) OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NextAlpha
 FROM T AS T1
```

And be aware, that the `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` would work with this kind of query only, you should rather use a decent sort criterium.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. saved couple of hours.